# Regular expression for class using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using BeautifulSoup for easy scraping.

I have figured out there are more than 5 `div` in webpage which I want to scrap. Their names are different but has pattern.

These divs are:

```
divnewthing
divnew
divnewstring
```

etc

So the pattern is `divnew*` kind of regular expression.

And I am using:

```
soup.find('div', {"class": "divnew"})
```

at the moment.

I want to use regular expression somehow. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a [regular expression pattern](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) too:

```
soup.find('div', {"class": re.compile("^divnew")})
```

Or, a function, checking that a class name starts with `divnew`:

```
soup.find('div', {"class": lambda x: x and x.startswith("divnew"))})
```

Or, with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("div[class^=divnew]")
```